# Is there any Intel HD Graphics (Pentium G620) driver support for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

My processor is an Intel Pentium G620 2.6GHz. I cannot install graphics drivers provided by motherboard manufacturer. It shows

> Your computer does not meet minimum requirements.

So I tried downloading drivers from Intel's website and there is not support for Intel HD Graphics for Windows 10.

I also tried updating driver from device manager. At third attempt Windows downloaded a Intel HD Graphics driver. But I don't think that version is not working well with my computer. Many software not allowing hardware rendering, but they worked well when I had Windows 7.

Comment: Download [Intel driver update utility](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html). It will automatically detect and download latest supported driver.

Comment: There is no Win10 support for anything older than the Intel HD4000 series.

Comment: You can try installing the driver with compatibility settings for Windows 7 - right-click the installer file, select "Properties", then under "Compatibility", select "Windows 7 SP1". Then retry the install. The driver might work with Windows 10 too.

Comment: try [this driver](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/GRAPHICS-BOARD/INTEL/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-815102900-for-Windows-10-64-bit.shtml)

Comment: None of these worked :| if @Tetsujin is right I gotta change my processor then?

Comment: I think you'd either need to go back to WIn7/8 [whichever you had originally] or add a discreet graphics card.